# Save file> folder with Memo delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm french so sorry for my little language...

So, my project is here [Memo and create file and folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003927/memo-and-create-file-and-folder)

i have a problem with my code :

```
var
  path: String;
  F: TextFile;
  i, e: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if Length(Memo1.Lines[i]) > 0 then
    begin
      if Memo1.Lines[i][1] = '\' then // first character for file
        if Pos('.', Memo1.Lines[i]) > 0 then // confirm file
        begin
          path := extractfilepath(Edit1.Text) + Memo1.Lines[i];
          // showmessage(path);
          if not FileExists(path) then
          begin
            AssignFile(F, path);
            Rewrite(F);
            CloseFile(F);
          end;
        end;
      e := Length(Memo1.Lines[i]);
      case Memo1.Lines[i][e] of // last character for folder
        '\':
          begin
            path := extractfilepath(Edit1.Text) + Memo1.Lines[i];
            if not DirectoryExists(path) then
              ForceDirectories(path); // create folder
          end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

my structure in Tmemo is :

[image: structure of tmemo]

and my bad result:

[image: bad result]

i test first and last character for know what is it file or folder and my problem is file saved in currentPath, no in folder1:

Dir:

```
 folder1->file1.txt 
  folder2 ->file2.txt and file2-3.txt
   etc..
```

can you help me please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: shouldn't this line just include your folder `path := extractfilepath(Edit1.Text) + Memo1.Lines[i];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to test first.
`is the token a directory` then `isFolder:=true`.

"memo2" is just about to create file.txt easier. (more convenient)

**Delphi 5**

```
implementation

{$R *.DFM}

uses FileCtrl;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.Text:='test.txt'#13#10'folder1\'#13#10'\file1.txt'#13#10'folder2\'#13#10'\file2.txt'#13#10'\file2-3.txt'#13#10;
Memo2.Text:='';
Edit1.Text:='F:\testdir';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  path,aktpath,actToken: String;
  backSl : Char;
  i: Integer;
  isFolder:Boolean;
begin
backSl := #92; // This only for better reading the code in SO
isFolder:=false;
aktpath:='';actToken:='';
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if Length(Memo1.Lines[i]) > 0 then
    begin
      actToken:=Memo1.Lines[i];
      // Folder -----------------------------------------
      if copy(actToken,length(actToken),1)= backSl then begin
      if copy(Edit1.Text,length(Edit1.Text),1)= backSl then
                  path := Edit1.Text + actToken else
                  path := Edit1.Text + backSl + actToken;
         if not DirectoryExists(path) then
              ForceDirectories(path); // create folder
      isFolder:=true;
      aktpath:=path;
      continue;
      end;
      // File   -----------------------------------------
      if copy(actToken,1,1) = backSl then // first character for file
        if Pos('.', actToken) > 0 then // confirm file
        begin
          if isFolder then path:=aktpath + actToken else
                           path:=Edit1.Text + actToken;
          path:=StringReplace(path,'\\',backSl,[rfReplaceAll]);
          if not FileExists(path) then Memo2.Lines.SaveToFile(path);
          continue;
        end;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

UPDATE : \file1.txt:Hello to the world

```
var
[...]
actTokenTxt: String;
count: Integer;

begin
isFolder:=false;
[...]


// File   -----------------------------------------
      if copy(actToken,1,1) = backSl then // first character for file
        if Pos('.', actToken) > 0 then // confirm file
        begin
          count:=Pos(':', actToken);
          if count > 0 then begin
              actTokenTxt:=copy(actToken,1,count);
              Memo2.Text:=StringReplace(actToken,actTokenTxt,'',[]);
              actToken:=copy(actToken,1,count-1);;
          end;
          if isFolder then path:=aktpath + actToken else
                           path:=Edit1.Text + actToken;
          path:=StringReplace(path,'\\',backSl,[rfReplaceAll]);
          if not FileExists(path) then Memo2.Lines.SaveToFile(path);
          continue;
        end;
```

**Remember to delete file1.txt if it is present**
Do'nt forget to set `Memo2.Text:=''` if there is not `:` Otherwise, all files of the same text !!
Try it with `if count > 0 then begin [...] else Memo2.Text:=''`

Comment: Your script is work,good idea for using Tmemo2 so very thank you for your example...

Comment: Glad I could help. It is not necessary to call 'ExtractFilePath (Edit1.Text)'. Because if the path ends without "\", then `C:\mydir\mydir2` becomes to `C:\mydir\`. And that is not what you wanted to.

Comment: Hi moskito-x, Simple question, it's possible with your code i add text in file with delimiter example: file1.txt *:* write_is_work ?

Comment: @Kate Can you explain in more detail what you want to do?

Comment: Ok if i use delimiter **:** in memo example test.txt:hello  = write hello in test.txt

Comment: @Kate Look at my updated answer. test.txt do'nt start with `\\` .

Comment: @ moskito-x Than you for reply, yes for test it's perfect now, my solution for write text in file http://pastebin.com/81jkjXkA you have any suggestions?

Comment: You did not use Memo2.Text to write the file ?? Wy not ? Also do NOT use components (Edit3) `Edit3.Text := Path;` for that !! 
And if there is no `:` in your Token the file will not be written !!. Your logic does not apply then.

Comment: @Kate: If you have a new, separate question, ask it as one, and post your new code **here** in your new question instead of on pastebin. This question was answered and the answer accepted. Please don't change it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var
  folder_path, path: String;
  F: TextFile;
  i, e, num: Integer;

begin
  for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if Length(Memo1.Lines[i]) > 0 then
    begin
      e := Length(Memo1.Lines[i]);
      if Memo1.Lines[i][e] = '\' then // last character for folder
      begin
        num := StrToInt(Memo1.Lines[i][7]);
        folder_path := Copy(Memo1.Lines[i], 1, Length(Memo1.Lines[i])-1);
        path := extractfilepath(Edit1.Text) + Memo1.Lines[i];
        //showmessage(path);
        if not DirectoryExists(folder_path) then
          ForceDirectories(folder_path); // create folder
      end

      else if Memo1.Lines[i][1] = '\' then // first character for file
        if Pos('.', Memo1.Lines[i]) > 0 then // confirm file
        begin
          if (num = StrToInt(Memo1.Lines[i][6])) then
            path := extractfilepath(Edit1.Text) + folder_path + Memo1.Lines[i]
          else path := extractfilepath(Edit1.Text) + Memo1.Lines[i];
          //showmessage(path);
          if not FileExists(path) then
          begin
            AssignFile(F, path);
            Rewrite(F);
            CloseFile(F);
          end;
        end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This assumes that `folder#` will always be the folder string with # = number.
Similar with files.

Comment: **num := StrToInt(Memo1.Lines[i][7]);**  This assumes that all files are only 7 characters long and in the end have a number? In real life that is hardly the case! (preprogrammed errors).

Comment: @moskito-x it seemed from the OP code that files and folders have the same structure based on `folderCharacter` characters and its position in the string. But that is why I made the comment regarding the structure and used same OP code for the most part.

Comment: @moskito-x it works for that too :<) this code I tried before I posted. `num := StrToInt(Memo1.Lines[i][7]` only gets the number from the 7th position while that string is actually 9 characters long based on the OP images. I compare only the folder number with the files first number, so `file2-3.txt` would end up in `folder2`

Comment: Thank you for helped me, The problem is that the values ​​can be random and with your code it's no functional...